# Unterschied: "über die Straßen fahren" vs "auf den Straßen fahren"?

Tags: meaning, difference, preposition, standard-german

Ich habe Schwierigkeiten die Präposition *"über"* zu verstehen... Ich dachte immer, dass *"über"* nur benutzt wird, wenn man etwas _überquert (über die Straße geht), also quer durch etwas geht(Straße, Stadt, Grenze, etc). Aber im Satz:

> "Was für Fahrzeuge werden in der Zukunft über unsere Straßen fahren?"

was soll "über" dort bedeuten?? Es kann da nicht *"die Straße überqueren"* gemeint sein, oder?

Comment: Der Satz scheint aus einem russischen Deutsch-Lehrbuch zu stammen. Und ist erster Teil einer Aufgabenstellung mit anschließendem Text. Nachzulesen (ohne Bilder) [hier](https://wikireshebnik.ru/index.php/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%E2%84%962_-_%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB_3_%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_7_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%86%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D1%83_7_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0_-_%D0%91%D0%B8%D0%BC_%D0%98.%D0%9B.). Wer will findet das Buch auch online (Seite 108) ^^

Comment: stimmt, ich lese es jetzt durch, deshalb weiss ich nicht ob das Wort "über" wirklich so benutzt wird. Ausländerische Lehrbücher für Deutsch können manchmal altmodisch sein und ich weiss nicht ob Deutsche das Wort wikrlich so benutzen.

Comment: Weitere Beispiele (aus DWDS Korpusbelege): "Einmal pro Monat ist er in Rumänien und fährt über die gewundenen Straßen durch die Landschaft." "Wir sitzen also in einem Auto und fahren über eine Straße, ein einsames Band, das sich durch die Wüste nach Osten zieht." "Er fuhr vom militärischen Teil des Flughafens mit einer großen Autokolonne über abgesperrte Straßen zum Hotel Adlon am Brandenburger Tor."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Das ist eine interessante Frage. Interessant insofern, dass ich -als Muttersprachler- beide Begrifflichkeiten bisher ohne nachzudenken verwendet habe.

Beide Sätze klingen -erst mal- völlig natürlich und komplett austauschbar:

> Was für Fahrzeuge werden in der Zukunft auf unseren Straßen fahren?

oder

> Was für Fahrzeuge werden in der Zukunft über unsere Straßen fahren?

Dann habe ich aber genauer darüber nachgedacht und denke, man könnte man beiden Varianten einen leicht unterschiedlichen Kontext unterstellen.

"Auf der Strasse fahren" ist dabei für mich mehr eine "Zustandsbeschreibung": Autos fahren auf Strassen... Ein Zweck / eine Richtung / ein Ziel ist nicht impliziert.

"Über die Strasse fahren" ist mehr eine "Bewegung mit einem Ziel". Wie: Ich fahre "über die Hauptstrasse nach Hause". Oder (danke @olafant in den comments): "Ich fahre über Hamburg nach Berlin"

Dasselbe Phänomen lässt sich bei Schiffen nachvollziehen: Das Schiff "fährt" (schwimmt) auf dem Wasser (Zustandsbeschreibung)... ABER: Das Schiff fährt ÜBER das Meer nach Amerika (Richtung / Ziel)...

Interessant ist allerdings, dass bei "über die Strasse gehen" tatsächlich das überqueren der Strasse gemeint ist, und ich damit eher nicht das benutzen einer Strasse assoziieren würde.

Ob sich mein persönliches Sprachgefühl mit dem anderer deckt, weiss ich nicht. Aber eins kann ich sicher sagen: über die Straße fahren ist absolut gängig und normal.

Comment: +1, das ist *exakt* mein Eindruck.

Comment: Das passt schon auch für *über die Straße gehen*, wenn man die Bewegung mit Ziel als *etwas passieren* betrachtet. *Über* hat hier (im Gegensatz zu *auf*) eben nichts mit oberhalb zu tun. Man sagt ja auch: *Wir fahren über Hamburg nach Berlin.*

Answer (score 0):

Nach [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/%C3%BCber) Abschnitt Ⅰ 2 c γ, ist eine der Bedeutungen von *über*

> passierend, um an einen Ort zu gelangen, der jenseits davon liegt

Ich habe den Eindruck, dass bei dieser Formulierung die Straße in den Hintergrund gerückt wird im Vergleich zu

> Auf mit Schlaglöchern übersäten Straße kamen wir nach x.

wo eine Aussage bezüglich der Straße selbst gemacht wird.

Das schließt auch nahtlos an die weitere Bedeutung (DWDS Ⅲ 4), *bezeichnet das als Mittler dienende Zwischenglied*, im folgenden Beispiel an:

> Über einen Gentest konnte die Vaterschaft nachgewiesen werden.

Comment: From the DWDS usage database I gather that there is a difference between *auf* and *über*, but it's subtle. You use *über* a lot with the plural *Straßen*; you're not driving a specific route but just "around". There's one quote above that talks about a lonely desert highway, but I think in that case there's only one route possible so it doesn't matter.   that you don't have a route in mind. Ⅰ 2 c γ seems like the best match but don't think it's an exact fit. But, in my experience, DWDS doesn't always capture every possible shade of meaning. Still, it's my favorite German dictionary.